# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space?

Tags: java, file, csv, stringbuffer

I am writing list object's into a CSV file by using `StringBuffer` object, when the list contains less data our logic is working perfectly but when there is a large amount of data the in list then there's a problem and I get the error: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space problem`

Code snippet as follows :

```
StringBuffer report = new StringBuffer();
String[] column = null;
StringReader stream = null;
for (MassDetailReportDto dto: newList.values()) {
 int i = 0;
  column = new String[REPORT_INDEX];
  column[i++] = dto.getCommodityCode() == null ? " " :   dto.getCommodityCode();
  column[i++] = dto.getOaId() == null ? " " : dto.getOaId();
  //like this we are calling some other getter methods
  //After all getter methods we are appending columns to stringBuffer object
  report.append(StringUtils.join(column, PIPE));
  report.append(NEW_LINE);
  //now stringbuffer object we are writing to file
  stream = new StringReader(report.toString());
  int count;
  char buffer[] = new char[4096];
  while ((count = stream.read(buffer)) > -1) {
    //writing into file
    writer.write(buffer, 0, count);
  }
  writer.flush();
  //clearing the buffer
  report.delete(0, report.length());
}
```

Error is :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:99)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:393)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:120)
```

Could you please look into above code snippet and help me, it would be great help.

Comment: You can use the `-Xmx` option of `java` to increase to heap space. For example: `java -Xmx1024m Main`

Comment: You can increase the amount of memory available to Java as per the comment above.  Or, you can look at your logic and think about whether you really need to put your whole list into `report` when you are writing it out to `writer` on each iteration of the `for` loop.

Comment: Also - it is hard to assist with the detail of your query when the snippet you provide would not compile - you have `column` array set to null but then try to set elements of it using `column[i++] = ....` Also, `i` is not defined.  Can you ensure you provide a compilable [Minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: yes Richard we have increased the heap size and we have to write total list object into file!!   we have define all parameters even its working for small amount of dat, problem with only huge data. Above code is sample code.

Comment: This code just looks plain weird. Apart from the issues already mentioned: You create a `StringBuffer` that you append all your data to with the sole purpose of later writing the contents of that `SringBuffer` to an `OutputStream`. Why don't you just write directly to the stream? Use a BufferedWriter instead of rolling your own. And post working code and not something copy-and-pasted that cannot possibly be the code you are running.

Comment: That sample doesn't compile.  You need more information in there.  Particularly - how big is `column`? what is `i` and where does it get set / reset?  When you say "large amounts of data" do you mean the list gets very long or (I suspect) that the `MassDetailReportDto` objects in it get very large?  Does the `OutOfMemory` happen for the first item, last item, same item every time etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where does `column` get initialized?  I don't see it.  But it seems that's a likely culprit.  You are building a string array without clearing it out.  `column[i++]` .  Where do you clear out that array?  It should be scoped to the loop body, not outside of it.  So inside loop, declare your `String[] column` and use it within that scope.

Comment: Yes, I saw that after my initial post.  I've changed my answer to reflect it.

Comment: Thanks Madconan, we are creating string array with in the for loop column = new String[REPORT_INDEX];   but I missed it to post. Code snippet modified check it once.

Answer (score 0):

This seems logical to have out of memory error when the list size is big enough. Increasing the JVM heap size (using `-Xmx` and -`Xms` jvm args) would resolve the issue temporarily. However, ideally you should used paged access to the source of the items in the list. If the list is populated from database or webservice, it can easily be accessed in paged way.

Comment: We have increased JVM heap size up to 1GB but still facing the problem !!..Here for each row after writing into the file we are clearing the buffer but not understanding where the problem exactly!!

Comment: But the objects in the list itself do occupy heap space. So, better to access them in paged manner.

Comment: It's not the heap size, it's the code. He is obviously asking for OOM.